Is there a way to track usage of key mappings and/or functions in neovim?
I want to know which are the keys, mappings and functions I commonly use.
Is there a way to do that? What would be the preferred way to instrument mappings to save usage data?
Similar to wakatime/wakadev but focused in just Neovim's usage.

Maybe there you can find something.
